# Are there any neutral Force Users?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-force

Has there ever been any neutral force users (including but not limited to Jedi)? Someone who didn't belong neither to the light nor the dark side of the force, but somewhere in the middle?

I've never read any of the numerous books, but from the movies, I don't remember any mention of someone like this.

Comment: They're called [Gray Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gray_Jedi). I don't remember any from full canon sources but they are in Legends.

Comment: Not in the main canon but in the EU books and reference books there are mentions of loads of non-Jedi Force users.

Comment: @Richard can you expand that into an answer? I updated the question

Comment: Related possible dupe: [Were force-sensitives “required” to become Jedi?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48429/were-force-sensitives-required-to-become-jedi). Both answers discuss whether or not Force sensitives were necessarily required to align themselves.

Comment: @phantom42 those answers seem to be from a time before canon changed. And question intself seems to invoke EU. I think these are separate questions just on the basis of that

Comment: @Deltharis This new question mentions the books as well, most of which are EU/Legend. But

Comment: In Episode II, Mace Windu states: `You know, m'lady, that Count Dooku was once a Jedi.`. It was not impossible for Jedi to leave the order... Count Dooku, a Force user, who was not a Jedi anymore, but (as far as they knew at the moment) wasn't a Sith as well, could prove that the concept of Gray Jedi existed?

Comment: Isn't Leia neutral force user?

Comment: Whether the Jedi *knew* Dooku had become a Sith is irrelevant to the fact that he *was* a Sith.

Comment: @phantom42 - I mean that the fact that the Council considered Dooku as neither a Jedi nor a Sith at the moment, shows that the idea of a Gray Jedi wasn't extraordinary

Comment: What about [Je'daii](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Je%27daii_Order)?

Comment: Using everyone's favorite quotes, I'd say no, because, "If you're not with me, then you're my enemy!" On the other hand, "Only a Sith deals in absolutes," so maybe that is a possibility.

Comment: Ashoka Tano may be a candidate - in Star Wars: Rebels she is unaffiliated with the Jedi and uses white lightsabers to emphasize that statement. Not sure we've ever seen her use any dark side abilities, so while she's not affiliated with the Jedi she may still be 100% Light Side of the Force.

Comment: Jolee Bindo in KOTOR is a Grey Jedi.

Comment: Movies, no idea, but like @Wad Cheber said, Jolee Bindo was known as a "gray jedi" and rode the line between light and dark side. There are more like him in the expanded universe. http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Gray_Jedi

Comment: Jorus C'baoth was a *Dark Jedi*. The human was kind of a jerk; the clone was insane and did not abide the difference.

Answer (score 8):

### Yes

In *Star Wars: Rebels*, we are introduced to the Bendu:

[image]

The Bendu wields, or perhaps more accurately embodies, the balance between the light and the dark.

> KANAN: You’re a Force wielder. But you’re not a Jedi.
>
> BENDU: Wielder? Hmm. Jedi and Sith wield the Ashla and Bogan, the
> light and the dark. **I’m the one in the middle**, the Bendu.
>
> <sub>*Star Wars Rebels*: “Steps into Shadow”</sub>

That certainly sounds like “someone in the middle.”

Another example is the Father, from the Mortis arc of *The Clone Wars*.

[image]

According to [the Databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/father):

> In the mysterious realm of Mortis there exists a trio of beings able
> to wield the Force in ways no known mortals of the galaxy can. **The
> Father maintained balance between his Daughter and his Son, who
> expressed affinity to the light and dark side of the Force,
> respectively.**

Answer (score 2):

There are no '*neutral*' force-users seen in the [official Star Wars canon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Canon) (e.g the 6 Theatrical movies / the Clone Wars TV series / the Clone Wars film). Almost everyone we meet with any connection to the Force is either a fully paid-up Jedi or a Sith/Dark-Side user.

---

The closest we come in the EU is probably [Aurra Sing](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aurra_Sing). She used to be a Jedi Padawan but left the order to become a bounty hunter specialising in Jedi assassinations.

There's also mention of non-Jedi force-users within the various books (known as [Gray Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gray_Jedi)) as well as a host of non-jedi organisations found in the Lucasfilm licensed [Jedi Path Manual](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Star-Wars-Manual-Students-Force/dp/0857685872).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Aurra Sing (who shows up in Ep1) was a Padawan who left the order but never aligned with either side. Granted, she became a bounty hunter, but never became a Sith or even a Dark Jedi.

Comment: @Null I am not familiar with the cartoon - wookieepedia names their powers as "magicks", and those allow for feats I've never seen jedi/sith do. Is it confirmed that what they're doing is using the Force? If yes - you could make that into an answer

Comment: @Deltharis The first sentence of the Wookieepedia article mentions the Force, and Maul was a Nightbrother before he became a Sith (and he was obviously using the Force).

Comment: @Null I see nothing wrong in principle with Maul being a force user in addition to magick. Also, I have made that into a proper question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/74036/magic-in-star-wars

Comment: @null - Cheerfully corrected.

Comment: @phantom42 - Good point. She's definitely a dark side user, but not a Sith.

Comment: Isn't Leia neutral force user?

Comment: @SachinShekhar - No. She's weak in the force but strongly aligned with the light side. When she gains (some) control of her gifts in the EU novels, she basically becomes a jedi padawan

Comment: If a Jedi can become Sith, then a neutral one can become Jedi, too. I think, Leia was neutral during the events of the movies.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - She only uses her powers for good,

Comment: No, she didn't. I am talking about the movies.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - what are you talking about? Do we ever see her in the movies use any force powers?

Comment: @SSumner - She hears Luke under the Cloud City and she "knows" that he got off the Death Star (MKII) OK. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9077/did-princess-leia-ever-use-the-force

Comment: @richar - ah, I had forgotten about that.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - when do we see her use her powers not for good, or even in a gray area?

Comment: @SSummer After second Death Star was destroyed, she felt that from Luke.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - how is that in a gray area? That's not really using powers in any light- or dark-sided area, it's just sensing...

Comment: @SSummer Oh then, I don't know the definition of gray area.. :)

Comment: Is there any indication Sing is Force sensitive in the new canon?

Answer (score 0):

Jedi are good and Sith are evil. Neutral  Force users can use powers from the light and dark side of the force. Rey could use force lightning, she could keep the ones she loved from dying and she could use a power I've not seen or heard of until The Rise Of Skywalker. Item Transfer. Ben and Rey could both use Item Transfer. Darth Sidious told Anakin that he could not learn the power to save the ones he loved from a Jedi. I believe him. Jedi are trained to let it go. Yoda specifically told Anakin to let go of his fears. Rey and Ben are true neutral Force users. Never seen Ashoka use and dark side powers. Never saw Qui Gon use any dark side powers. A true neutral of the force does not serve the light or the dark. They make the light and the dark serve them.

Answer (score -3):

'Neutral' force users are called [Gray Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gray_Jedi).  One of the most popular force users that meet the criteria for being a Gray Jedi is Qui Gon Jinn.  Qui Gon used both light and dark force abilities and light and dark light saber techniques, however, he was more of a light heavy-gray force user.  Though he used [dark side techniques](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Jedi) from time to time, he never truly strayed from the light side.  It's one of the main reasons the Jedi Council never promoted him past Master and never allowed him to sit on the Council.

Comment: Qui-Gonn is far from neutral. He's a Jedi master.

Comment: Jedi Masters can be neutral, Jedi Masters on the council could not be neutral.  Not to mention, I said he met the criteria for being neutral and that he was the closest to being neutral.  Not once did I say that he was neutral.

Comment: I'd imagine he'd be quite offended to be called neutral, having nearly been killed on Jedi business at least 10 times in the last decade (9 if you don't consider that business on Cato Neimoidia to count).

Comment: Just because he was close to being a gray Jedi, doesn't mean he wasn't 100% Jedi.  There were Jedi masters that explicitly used dark skills.  There are three types of Jedi, dark, gray, and light, then there's the Sith.

Comment: Gray Jedi are Jedi that use both light and dark force abilities.  They don't always adhere to either side's teachings.  Qui-Gon sought revenge a few times, something a Dark Jedi does.  Qui-Gon very often disobeyed orders and went against the Jedi Council.  Not something a full light side Jedi does.  Even Dooku stated that Jinn would be torn over which side to take during the clone wars.

Comment: Your answer might get better reception if you included your sources. Now it just looks like your personal opinion. Also, per Wookieepedia there is no jedi rank higher than master...

Comment: Except grand master, titles both Luke Skywalker and Yoda held.  Just an FYI, wookiepedia is as justifiable a resource as wikipedia.  But I'll place the reference links regardless

Answer (score -5):

Three types of Jedi

**Light**: Fully light side users who are like Yoda, Obi-Wan Kenobi and all those guys/girls. Light Jedi only use weak force powers that are for the light such as mind tricks, telekinesis (force waves/pushes and throws/repulsions), and non-aggressive uses of the force.

**Dark Jedi**: These guys/girls are not quite Jedi and not quite Sith, but are on the dark side of the force.

There are two Dark Jedi:

*Jedi version*: They seek to make the Jedi Order a Dark Jedi Order but hide within the order, pretending to be benevolent Jedi when they are Dark Jedi with hateful feelings of the Sith but are not true Sith themselves.

*Sith Version*: They are on the Dark Side and a Sith Lord but consider themselves Jedi, with the moral codes and things the Jedi have but for the sith.

**Gray Jedi** are truly neutral- not one side or the other.

Then there's **Light Sith**: Sith who follow the ways of the light (basically a good guy Sith).

But there should be Gray Sith too to balance it out, like the Gray jedi. The Gray Sith doesn't work for a specific side either, but is a Sith instead of Jedi. There should Jensaari class too. And also a Jith class Jedi/Sith, like Jensaari but are true Jedi mixed with Sith, not just force users alone. So a difference between Jensaari and Jith or Sithi- Jith is the Jedi one and Sithi is the Sith one.

Comment: This is almost unintelligible, even after the edits to add line breaks and proper capitalization.  Can you clarify it, please?  Proper sentence structure, syntax, grammar, etc, would be very helpful.